# Add two Ids on unsubscribe link in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I have a global footer in the marketing cloud and there I put a unsubscribe link in which I created a site.come page and passed AccoundID.
So my updated requirement is, I need to pass LeadID too there. I am using two data extension one for Account and other for Lead. So whenever leadID would be there, LeadID should be worked and in other case AccoundID should be worked. my unsubscribe link is as follows https://google.com?Id=%%AccountID%%LeadID&EmaiId=%%PersonEmail%%">Unsubscribe />
When I am passing both IDs and getting one of the only ID lets say I am getting only AccountID, it's giving me an error  LeadID was not found.
So is there any way in which I can use both IDs in the link and the Id I am getting whether it is of Account as well as Lead, It should work.
Thanks

Comment: You need to have attributes named AccountID and LeadID in the Data Extension you are sending too. So either you add both IDs to the Data Extension you are sending too. Or you use one of the Lookup functions in AMPScript. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookup.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the ID as a general ID of the record that wants to unsubscribe, regardless which one this is, instead of two separate IDs, and then use the following to determine which object this is and which table should be updated:

```
%%[
SET @Id = [retrieve Id passed as parameter]
    IF NOT EMPTY(@Id) THEN
        / Check if it’s a Lead or Account/
        IF Substring(@subscriber_key, 1,3) == "00Q" THEN
            / it’s a Lead /
            SET @UpdateLead = [use an Update function to update your DE with Leads]
        ELSE
            / it’s an Account /
            SET @UpdateAccount = [use an Update function to update your DE with Accounts]                                      
        ENDIF 
    ENDIF
]%%
```

**EDIT:**

Based on new details provided, this should work:

```
%%[
SET @AccountID = [retrieve Account ID]
SET @LeadID = [retrieve Lead ID]
SET @email = emailaddr
Set @link = "http://site.com"

IF NOT EMPTY(@AccountID) THEN
    SET @url = concat(@link,"?Id=",@AccountID,"&EmaiId=",@email)
ELSE
    SET @url = concat(@link,"?Id=",@LeadID,"&EmaiId=",@email)
ENDIF
]%%

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@url)=%%">Unsubscribe</a>
```